# unioning inheriting children back together

Tags: multiple-inheritance, intersection, children

i have a parent class Person, with children Employee, Member. at some point i will need an Employee to become an employee and a member at same time, holding all the attributes available for both employee and member. how could this be achieved while maintaining only one database record for that person who has moved from being Employee to being both Employee and a Member? i guess multiple inheritance could solve the problem by creating a new class that inherits from those two children, but i am using c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some things, inheritance is just not the best choice.

If someone who is an `Employee` can become a `Member` or vice versa, and especially if someone can be both at once, this should probably just not be an inheritance relation in the first place.

I would change the `Employee` and `Member` classes into subclasses of a new component called something like `Role`, and change the `Person` class to have a field that is a set of `Role` objects.

With this representation, someone can have both `Employee` and `Member` roles.

Comment: so now i will have class Person with fields (Name, Phone, Roles) where Roles is a list of class Role, Role is a parent class where Member and Employee inherits from, am i getting it right?